# Name for isomorphisms canonically identifying all elements in a category

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

Say in a category, for any two objects $A,B$, we have an isomorphism $\iota_{AB}:A\to B$ with the property that $\iota_{BC}\circ\iota_{AB}=\iota_{AC}$ and $\iota_{AA}=\mathit{id}$.

Essentially, such a (family of) isomorphisms canonically identifies all objects in the category.

Is there a name for this property?

Examples:

- In the category of singleton sets, there is a unique isomorphism between any two objects, it has this property.
- In the category of one-dimensional vector spaces with designated bases, there is a unique isomorphism that maps a basis state to a basis state. It has this property. (This is the situation I am faced with and I want to use a standard term for this notion in my paper, if at all possible.)
- In the category of totally ordered sets of a fixed finite cardinality $n$, the unique order preserving bijection between objects has this property.

Comment: Doesn’t every category in which all objects are isomorphic have this property? Fix an object $X$, and for each object $A$ pick an isomorphism $\varphi_A: X\to A$. Then let $\iota_{AB}=\varphi_B\varphi_A^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah, but reading the question more carefully, I think you’re asking for a name for the collection of isomorphisms, rather than a name for a category which has such a collection?

Comment: Upon choosing an object, this feels like it's equivalent to the data of a fixed adjoint equivalence to the trivial category.

Comment: I have never heard of a name for such a thing, but the first name that occurs to me is "wide clique".

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes, I am trying to name the property. Basically, I would write a sentence such as "we show that $\iota_{AB}$ is XXX, that is satisfies ...". If there exists no term, that's also ok, then I'll make up something, but I wanted to use an existing term if there is one.

Comment: @JeremyRickard It's not really relevant for my question, but about the question whether every category has such an isomorphism: I'm not convinced. The construction you mention would need the existence of a family $\phi_A$, which, I think, would need some strong form of the axiom of choice (over categories as opposed to over sets). So depending on the axioms you are willing to use, even the existence might be a problem.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. I was allowing myself enough “choice”. But I think only as much as is needed to prove that the two familiar definitions of an equivalence of categories (has an inverse up to natural isomorphism, and is fully faithful and essentially surjective) are the same?

Comment: @JeremyRickard To be honest, I can't confirm or deny the latter since me and category theory have only a passing acquaintance. Personally, I'm often a bit wary of category-theory proofs because I can't see the way how to break them down to a concrete axiom system (e.g., ZFC, HOL, or whichever) but it might be my own limitation.